# How can I maintain the same distance between two points over the outer line of the semi-circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry

I am trying to maintain the same distance between the two circles(green).

Code: [here](http://codepen.io/rajagopalcr7/pen/pEjpLE)

**Html:**

```
<div id="red" class="s">
            <div id="svg-red">
                <div id="r-c-1" class="r-c">a</div>
                <div id="r-c-2" class="r-c">b</div>
                <div id="r-c-3" class="r-c">c</div>
                <div id="r-c-4" class="r-c">d</div>       </div>
</div>
<div id="green" class="s"></div>
```

**Css:**

```
#red,#green,#blue{
            width : 100%;
            height : 900px; 
            position : relative;
        }
        #red{           
            background : red;
            position:relative;
        }
        #green{         
            background : green;
        }

.r-c{
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: purple;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 50px;
            line-height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: calc(50% - 50px);
            left: calc(50% - 50px);
        }
        #svg-red{
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            border-radius: 300px;
            bottom: -300px;
            left: calc(50% - 300px);
            background: yellow;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){ 
var a = 36;
        $(".r-c").each(function(index,data){            
            var b = a + a * index;
            var x =  300 * Math.cos(b*Math.PI/180);
            var y =  300 * Math.sin(b*Math.PI/180);
            $(data).css("transform","translate("+x+"px,"+-y+"px)");
        });
}
```

In the above example distance between **a-b,b-c,c-d** are equal, but the distance between starting point to **a** and **d** to last point are unequal.
I want to maintain the same distance between the points through out the outer line of the semi circle.

Comment: To clarify: You want the visible segments on the circle outside of the point disks to be approximately equal?

Comment: Yes @LutzL, all the points(In this example its green circles) should be separated by equal distance and first circle should be start from non-zero degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a big radius R (=300) and the disk radius r (=50). Each of the small disks occupies in first approximation an angle section of

```
phi = (2*r)/R
```

on the big circle. If you want to place n (=4) small disks on the circle, there are n+1 (=5) spaces in between that you want to get of equal angle psi. Thus

```
Pi = n*phi + (n+1)*psi
```

or

```
psi = (Pi - n*phi)/(n+1)
```

The centers of the small disks then need to have the angles

```
psi+phi/2+k*(phi+psi)
```

---

It may be that after this elaborate adaptation the optical impression is that the outer segments are now too short, caused by not having the second fat end point.

Comment: What it is "k" here? And I presume the formula goes like this, x=R*Math.cos(psi+phi/2+k*(phi+psi)); and y=R*Math.sin(psi+phi/2+k*(phi+psi)); is it right?

Comment: yes, k is the index from 0 to n-1. And yes, the formula was for the angle in the polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you're setting `(x,y)` but you were basing the angle on degrees, when you needed to be basing the angle on radians. This is what you want:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var radius = 300;
  var $rcs = $(".r-c");
  var numAngles = $rcs.length + 1;
  var radians = Math.PI / numAngles;
  $rcs.each(function(index,data) {
    var polarCoords = (index + 1) * radians;
    var x = radius * Math.cos(polarCoords);
    var y = radius * Math.sin(polarCoords);
    $(data).css(
      "transform",
      "translate("+x+"px,"+-y+"px)"
    );
  });
}
```

This will display each one at an equidistant angle from 0 - (pi/2) depending on the number of `.r-c` elements you have.

Note: it may look like the first and last elements are not equidistant, but that is an illusion. The center of each purple circle will be equidistant from its neighbor and from theta = 0; theta = Pi.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the result. By the way I want first circle to be start from non-zero deg.

Comment: it definitely works... i tried it in the codepen you posted. what is the the angle of the first circle's position? just offset the value of `polarCoords` by that value in radians and you're set

Comment: Oh I see what you're getting at. I'm looking at it now.

Comment: I think I've figured it out @rcr

Comment: Theoretically your approach is 100% correct. But It's not illusion @Derek, because when i make the circles(green) to smaller radius then it looks fine. So, It needs some changes in DOM, CSS or JS to make or at least to look like distance between circles(green) are same.